# boost asio streambuf releasing memory while resizing while internal thread reads into buffer

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost-asio

I have a boost asio app that works well most of the time but every now and then valgrind shows an "unaddressable byte" error. I suspect what is happening is as follows:

- The async_read_transfer_at_least() call is resizing the boost::asio::streambuf and while doing so it frees the memory but it hasn't resized it yet.
- At this point there is a context switch to some internal boost thread that may have been spawned when io_service.run() was executed. This thread reads the data from the socket and tries to service a async_read request that was queued up and tries to store the data in the buffer.
- But the buffer has been "freed" by the async_read() which is in process hence resulting in an unaddressable byte.

After a lot of researching and reading most posts on asio and streambufs I haven't been able to find a clean way to fix this. The valgrind output is posted:

```
==2759== Syscall param recvmsg(msg.msg_iov[0]) points to unaddressable byte(s)
==2759==    at 0x3FB02E9920: __recvmsg_nocancel (in /lib64/libc-2.12.so)
==2759==    by 0x413897: boost::asio::detail::socket_ops::recv(int, iovec*, unsigned long, int, boost::system::error_code&) (socket_ops.ipp:784)
==2759==    by 0x41391E: boost::asio::detail::socket_ops::non_blocking_recv(int, iovec*, unsigned long, int, bool, boost::system::error_code&, unsigned long&) (socket_ops.ipp:873)
==2759==    by 0x451063: boost::asio::detail::reactive_socket_recv_op_base<boost::asio::mutable_buffers_1>::do_perform(boost::asio::detail::reactor_op*) (reactive_socket_recv_op.hpp:58)
==2759==    by 0x410520: boost::asio::detail::reactor_op::perform() (reactor_op.hpp:40)
==2759==    by 0x411FD2: boost::asio::detail::epoll_reactor::descriptor_state::perform_io(unsigned int) (epoll_reactor.ipp:623)
==2759==    by 0x4120D2: boost::asio::detail::epoll_reactor::descriptor_state::do_complete(boost::asio::detail::task_io_service*, boost::asio::detail::task_io_service_operation*, boost::                    system::error_code const&, unsigned long) (epoll_reactor.ipp:649)
==2759==    by 0x410387: boost::asio::detail::task_io_service_operation::complete(boost::asio::detail::task_io_service&, boost::system::error_code const&, unsigned long) (task_io_service                    _operation.hpp:38)
==2759==    by 0x412BD3: boost::asio::detail::task_io_service::do_run_one(boost::asio::detail::scoped_lock<boost::asio::detail::posix_mutex>&, boost::asio::detail::task_io_service_thread                    _info&, boost::system::error_code const&) (task_io_service.ipp:372)
==2759==    by 0x4126FA: boost::asio::detail::task_io_service::run(boost::system::error_code&) (task_io_service.ipp:149)
==2759==    by 0x412EC8: boost::asio::io_service::run() (io_service.ipp:59)
==2759==    by 0x42F57F: abc::io::Reactor<boost::asio::io_service, abc::io::BoostNetworkSvc>::start() (abc_io_reactor.hpp:82)
==2759==  Address 0x4c34620 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 512 free'd
==2759==    at 0x4A06C79: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:530)
==2759==    by 0x44CEB5: __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<char>::deallocate(char*, unsigned long) (new_allocator.h:110)
==2759==    by 0x449943: std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<char> >::deallocate(std::allocator<char>&, char*, unsigned long) (alloc_traits.h:383)
==2759==    by 0x4444C9: std::_Vector_base<char, std::allocator<char> >::_M_deallocate(char*, unsigned long) (stl_vector.h:178)
==2759==    by 0x4443C7: std::vector<char, std::allocator<char> >::_M_default_append(unsigned long) (vector.tcc:578)
==2759==    by 0x43DBC4: std::vector<char, std::allocator<char> >::resize(unsigned long) (stl_vector.h:676)
==2759==    by 0x441212: boost::asio::basic_streambuf<std::allocator<char> >::reserve(unsigned long) (basic_streambuf.hpp:326)
==2759==    by 0x43A4C1: boost::asio::basic_streambuf<std::allocator<char> >::prepare(unsigned long) (basic_streambuf.hpp:207)
==2759==    by 0x433349: boost::asio::detail::read_streambuf_op<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp, boost::asio::stream_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >, std::al                    locator<char>, boost::asio::detail::transfer_at_least_t, boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf1<void, abc::io::IProtocol, boost::system::error_code const&>, boost::_bi::list2<boost::_                    bi::value<abc::io::IProtocol*>, boost::arg<1> (*)()> > >::operator()(boost::system::error_code const&, unsigned long, int) (read.hpp:623)
==2759==    by 0x42C360: boost::asio::async_result<boost::asio::handler_type<boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf1<void, abc::io::IProtocol, boost::system::error_code const&>, boost:                    :_bi::list2<boost::_bi::value<abc::io::IProtocol*>, boost::arg<1> (*)()> >, void (boost::system::error_code, unsigned long)>::type>::type boost::asio::async_read<boost::asio::basic_strea                    m_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp, boost::asio::stream_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >, std::allocator<char>, boost::asio::detail::transfer_at_least_t, boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost:                    :_mfi::mf1<void, abc::io::IProtocol, boost::system::error_code const&>, boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::value<abc::io::IProtocol*>, boost::arg<1> (*)()> > >(boost::asio::basic_stream_socke                    t<boost::asio::ip::tcp, boost::asio::stream_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >&, boost::asio::basic_streambuf<std::allocator<char> >&, boost::asio::detail::transfer_at_least_t, boost                    ::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf1<void, abc::io::IProtocol, boost::system::error_code const&>, boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::value<abc::io::IProtocol*>, boost::arg<1> (*)()> >&&) (rea                    d.hpp:715)
```

Comment: This calls for a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)/[MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Right now 99.9% says you have mis-managed the lifetime of the buffer. There's way too much hidden in the code (sic, there is none?): are you using threads, are you using shared pointers, are you using coroutines,...

Comment: No explicit threads, only any internal threads that may be spawned by boost asio. No shared pointers. There is a class an instance of which is created for the lifetime of the program and that instance contains an instance of boost::asio::streambuf which is used for ALL I/O. Reading from it is done via a std::istream

Comment: I'll check back when the question is updated with some code.